# Get an object scanned for use in blender

Tags: modeling

i have a few objects as prototypes and would like to get them 3d scanned for use in blender, anyone know if this is possible and where I could get this done...thanks

Comment: Surch online for photogramtiy programmes i think some are free,

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Search for "3d scan service" in the search engine of your choice and also put your country/location there.

Comment: Gleb Alexandrov answers a question about this in a recent podcast. It's Agisoft PhotoScan vs. 123D Catch, which is free.
I have not tried any of these myself, but at least here are two options for you to explore.

Answer (score 2):

What is the size of these objects?  The scale of the objects is going to matter a lot.  Many dental labs have 3d scanners with accuracy approaching 10microns, and scan volumes up to 15cm x 15cm x 15cm.  Find a local dental lab, call them, and ask if they can scan a generic object for you.

Comment: Who voted this down?  How is this not a useful answer?  OP asked WHERE it's possible to get objects scanned.  When I was in school, several dental labs scanned objects for me and provided me the scanned STL files.

Answer (score 2):

There are many different programs available for 3D Scanning. I think these are probably the best (give highest quality results) and are the easiest to use.

- [RealityCapture](https://www.capturingreality.com/), great for huge environments taken from drones but it's very expensive.
- [Agisoft Photoscan](http://www.agisoft.com/), probably the best value imo but still a tad expensive
- [Meshroom](https://github.com/alicevision/meshroom), free on github, I've had pretty good results with this
- 123D Catch, rubbish results but free and very easy to use. I have a feeling it's been discontinued tho.

All of these can export the mesh as .OBJ I think, blender can import this. Be prepared for a slow experience though, 3D scans can have millions of poly's.

You'll need a decent camera to take photographs of your object, a modern phone camera will probably work ok but a DSLR will be preferable. When you take photos make sure there is plenty of overlap between images.

To get the best results either make use of lighting equipment indoors to create an even lighting environment, or wait until an overcast day comes and go outside. Never 3D scan on a bright sunny day as you'll have very harsh shadows which will be 3D scanned and then you'll have a permanent shadow in blender.

It should be noted that you cannot 3D scan (with photogrammetry anyway) transparent or reflective surfaces as the software cannot determine which is the object and which is a reflection, you'll get nasty artifacts.

Once you've imported into blender you'll probably want to use the [decimate modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html) set to between 0.05 and 0.5 depending on how detailed you want the final mesh to be. In my experience I can set it to as low as  0.1 and not even lose any detail while reducing the number of verts by 90%.

If you want to get fancy, then you could [retopologize](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0o5soNCxiM) the mesh and [bake](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r-cGjVKvGw) the normals from the high density mesh to the retopologized mesh.

CG Geek has a good [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4NTf0hMjtY) on using meshroom. Gleb also has a few tutorials on 3d Scanning: [Photoscan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ewl-Ij0pF0M), [123D Catch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3Yo26yNgSU), [Visual SFM and Meshlab](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEAbXYDzUjU).

Answer (score 0):

There is the 123D Catch App just like michaelh mentioned. There is another way to create a scanned image. Take pictures of your object  from all directions including the top of the head.

Go to http://www.123dapp.com/
Click on the project tab and then on "Submit Project" scroll down to Images and add your pictures and it should process the it for you from there.